# Consider phrases with more than one word in stopwords.txt

Tags: apache, solr, filter

I have a *stopwords.txt* configured, it works fine.

The problem is when I want to search for a phrase which is compose just for words included in *stopwords.txt*. 
Solr is not returning results.
For example, in *stopwords.txt* I have this words:

```
other
the
cat
```

When I search for: **cat**, Solr omit the result, same for **the** and **cat**. That's fine.

But when I search for: **the cat**, Solr is doing the same, omitting the results, and that's exactly what I want to avoid. I want everything containing **the cat** to be returned.

Thanks in advance

PS: This is my configuration line

```
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The StopFilterFactory evaluates each token, and determines whether that token is an exact match for one of the stop words. To keep the phrase, "the cat" in your search, you need to make sure that it isn't tokenized into "the" and "cat", and there are various ways to do so.

The approach I would recommend would be to modify the phrase using a `SynonymFilterFactory` in your analysis before the `StopFilterFactory`:

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt"
                                            ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
```

The rules defined in `synonyms.txt` can act on multiple tokens is sequence. For example, if this rule appears in `synonyms.txt`:

```
the cat => thecat
```

Then the two-token sequence "the cat" will be replaced by the single token "thecat". Because "thecat" is not one of your stop words, the `StopFilterFactory` will not act on it.

If you follow this approach, it's important to apply this filter in both your index and query analysis (if they differ in the first place). This way, the document that contains "the cat" will have "thecat" in the index, and a user who searches for "the cat" will have "thecat" in their applied query.

Comment: I think it doesn't resolve my problem cause I have a huge list of stopped words and I can't make combination for all of them inside synonyms.txt, isn't it?

Comment: That depends on what you need to do. You have a huge list of stop words, but is your list of exceptions (e.g. "the cat") also huge? Your synonyms.txt file can be fairly large, but it could start to get inefficient at some point. If there are enough exceptions to when you want to allow your stop words to be filtered, do you need to include them in `stopwords.txt` in the first place?

Comment: For instance, if you want to block "the" or "cat" but not "the cat" is that because the phrase "the cat" is important in your records, or because you don't want to block consecutive stop words in general?

Comment: It's because I don't want to block consecutive stop words in general!

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the `StopFilterFactory`. People generally only apply stop words where they are reasonably confident that those words will _never_ be important in a search. **the** is a common stop word, but **cat** is generally not. If the purpose of your stop word filtering is to allow results to match on only part of a query, you could try looking into the `mm` parameter of the Dismax and Extended Dismax Query Handlers. For example, the query argument `mm=2<80%` tells Solr that two query terms or 80% of the terms (whichever is greater) must match for a record to count.

Comment: I was doing some tests. 
I tried to search by "the cat", surrounded by double quotes, in theory that should avoid the stopwords.txt filter but it doesn't happen, I mean, Solr don't return the item with name **the cat**. Is that normal? 

BTW: Nor **cat** or **the** are words in my stopwords.txt, I have a spanish website consuming this Solr instance, I'm using them just as example :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72271/discussion-between-oriam-and-frances).